# SSIS OData Package Fails on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

Awhile back, I created several SSIS packages, in SSDT 2015, that were deployed to a SQL Server 2016 SSIS instance. They were scheduled with agent jobs and run using basic auth.

Currently, in both SSDT directly and in the SQL 2016 instance, everything is working as expected. When I deployed them to a new SQL Server 2017 server, after changing the destination data sources to the new server, I get the following:
[image: SSIS Error Message]
I have tried:

- Running they package using windows auth using a proxy account
- Running in 32 bit
- Installing the Client Components SDK (not installed in previously working server)
- Modified the IE Proxy settings to ensure access (connecting to INTERNAL SharePoint)
- Ensured target version was set to SQL Server 2017

I have tried pretty much everything that the first few pages of Google has to offer under several different searches. I am truly at a loss for what to try next. Please let me know if you have any suggestions of where to look or what to try.

Thank you.

Comment: My guess, not having used the component, is that the 2016 release of the OData source component can't be directly upgraded with the 2017 release. Best approach would be to open the SSIS package using the 2017 tooling and see if there are warnings/errors once the package is upgraded

Comment: That or the connection manager doesn't play nicely in 2017.

Comment: Good idea. I need to figure out the tooling... It sounds like it used full Visual Studio which, for enterprise, requires licensing... Old tooling used to be free.

Comment: SSDT works with Visual Studio Community for 2019. It should be free for development purposes. Either SSDT installs the Visual Studio shell for development or an extension is how it gets into 2017